# Efficient way to calculate common elements in two ordered arrays

Tags: arrays

Logically it should only take one pass of both arrays to find common elements but what's the most **cpu efficient** way to do this in code?

One example that works (Java):

```
public Long[] commonElements(long[] array1, long[] array2) {
    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;
    List<Long> common = new ArrayList<>();
    while(i1 < array1.length && i2< array2.length){
        if(array1[i1] == array2[i2]){
            common.add(array1[i1]);
            i1++;
            i2++;
        } else if(array1[i1] > array2[i2]){
            i2++;
        } else {
            i1++;
        }
    }
    return common.toArray(new Long[common.size()]);
}
```

---

**EDIT:**
Ideally the function should work if both the arrays are in either descending or ascending order

Comment: It seems you answered your own question. The most CPU efficient way will be to do it in Assembly language, though ;-)

Comment: @Kenney I was hoping someone would tell me not to use Collections :p

Comment: Nah, they're too neat not to use! But yes, it does take 2 passes over the common elements collection (probably)...

Comment: @Kenney I noticed my method only works if both the arrays are in ascending order. Is there a solution that would work even if they were both descending?

Comment: Yes, as long as they are ordered. Change `>` into `<` and you're mostly there. Or you could reverse the arrays or use a reverse iterator.

Comment: The best algorithm would of course not know what order the elements are in and include a linear sort algorithm. It can be done in `O(n)`..